# Combine all same year and month date into one string in php

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

Hello there can you help me guys, I want to display all same date by year and month into one string.

```
DATABASE
+----------+----------------------+
| title    |    date_issued       |
+----------+----------------------+
| TITLE_1  |    2017-03-04        |
+----------+----------------------+
| TITLE_2  |    2017-03-17        |
+----------+----------------------+
| TITLE_3  |    2017-03-20        |
+----------+----------------------+
| TITLE_4  |    2017-04-01        |
+----------+----------------------+


AND I WANT TO BECOME WITH TO DISPLAY IN MY WEBSITE



   **ARCHIVE MENU**
   March 2017
   April 2017
   and so on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate just the year and month

```
select CONCAT(year(date_issued), month(date_issued)) as yearmonth from ....
```

Comment: He want the name of month too.

Comment: Thank you @paulib for your code can you give me full suggested sql code i don't how to work with concat im new with it.

Comment: @MOJOJO_06 The concat portion is there for you. Did you try it? What were your results. Is there still a portion that is unclear? I would recommend against getting the month in the query as shown in the CASE in the other answer and select "month(date_issued) as month" as a number and generate the month in English letters in code.

Comment: @paullb its not merging all same month.

Comment: @MOJOJO_06 Can you please elaborate? What result were you expecting, what result did you get?    If you need to get a sum or count please use GROUP BY as per normal.

Comment: it display month and year, but what i want is to merge all same month in a year, for example on my above code.

Comment: As I said, use GROUP BY to bring together what you need for a month.  e.g. select month(issue_date) as month .... group by month

Answer (score 0):

```
Query:

SELECT 
CONCAT(
    CASE MONTH(date_issued)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'January'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'February'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'March'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'April'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'May'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'June'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'July'
        WHEN 8 THEN 'August'
        WHEN 9 THEN 'September'
        WHEN 10 THEN 'October'
        WHEN 11 THEN 'November'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'December'
    END
,' ',
YEAR(date_issued)
) AS DATE FROM my_table ORDER BY date_issued ASC
```

> MySQL CONCAT() function is used to add two or more strings.
>
> • There may be one or more arguments. • Returns the string that
>   results from concatenating the arguments. • Returns a nonbinary
>   string, if all arguments are nonbinary strings. • Returns a binary
>   string, if the arguments include any binary strings. • If the argument
>   is numeric, it is converted to its equivalent nonbinary string form. •
>   Returns NULL if any argument is NULL.

Source: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php

Comment: Thank you Fernando then what should be the execution of this? I mean Month first then year, sorry for being a beginner question.

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-date_format-function.php

Answer (score 0):

We can simplify it even more as mysql has a function to get month name for us and I use it all the time.

`SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', MONTHNAME(date_issued), YEAR(date_issued)) from your_table;`

the `WS` part just means with separator so we can declare the concatenated string separator as the first param. Real handy when concatenating more than one field.

**Update**

Also im struggling to understand the question but if you are trying to group data by year and month you can add the grouping to the end of my query above and then add some `SUM` or `COUNT` operaters to get summary of data for that month e.g

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS(' ', MONTHNAME(date_issued), YEAR(date_issued)) as 'Date',
    SUM(numeric_field) as 'total volume of my numeric field',
    COUNT(id) as 'total count of my table data',
 FROM your_table
 GROUP YEAR(date_issued), MONTH(year_issued)
 ORDER BY (date_issued);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function to convert a DATE value into a string representation in a specified format. To get those ordered by "date" value, we can convert those strings back to a `DATE` datatype, using the STR_TO_DATE function.

It appears that we want a distinct list of "Month YYYY" values. We can use a `GROUP BY` clause to collapse the rows.

As an example:

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.date_issued,'%M %Y') AS `**ARCHIVE MENU**`
   FROM mytable t
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.date_issued,'%M %Y')
  ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(t.date_issued,'%M %Y'),'%Y-%m-01') ASC
```

--

This is just a guess, it's not entirely clear what you are attempting to achieve.